# Safari doesn't calculate rem units correct when scaling with @media (width/height/background-size)

Tags: css, safari, media-queries, font-size, dimensions

When using rem as units in css, scaling doesn't really work in Safari (both PC and Mac).

Example located at http://jsfiddle.net/L25Pz/3/

Markup:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
html { font-size:62.5% }

div { background:url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png); background-size:275px 95px; background-size:27.5rem 9.5rem; background-repeat:no-repeat; }
img { width:27.5rem; height:9.5rem; }
p { font-size:5rem; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size:50%;} /* should render everything * 0.8 */
}
```

​
​... renders a image in the size of 275px * 95px when the browser window is wider then 600px - in all browsers. Also, when triggering the media query, the image and the background adjusts it's width and height to 220px * 76px.

BUT - using Safari, the width and height is set to 247px * 75px. Which isn't * 0.8, it's something else...

The font-size of the paragraph on the other hand is rendered correctly: 40px when hooked on the query.

Mighty weird if you ask me. 
Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to set `-webkit-text-size-adjust` to `none` or else webkit will scale up the font size to a readable size:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size:50%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }  /* should render everything * 0.8 */  
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Turns out that rem works fine with font-size set in pixels too: http://jsfiddle.net/L25Pz/5/ (webkit renders better while resizing between media-queries).

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by changing the percentages by pixels

```
    @media (max-width: 96em) {
     html {
        font-size: 8px;
        }
     }
```

The browser uses a standard font size of **16px**. When we use *rem* for adaptation, for simplicity of calculations we specify a font size of 62.5% of 16px, which is 1em = 10px. When we adapt to other resolutions, we change this value proportionally. 
For example, for a resolution of 1280px it will be

1920/1280=1.5, 62.5/1.5=41.667(%).

At 1440px - 62.5/(1920/1440)=46.875(%).

All browsers except Safari understand when in media queries font-size is specified as a percentage. I solved the problem by converting the percentage to pixels.

1280: 41,667% * 16px = 6.66672 px

1440: 16 * 0,46875 = 7,5.

And so on.

Comment: Hi - could you add some details to your answer about why this works/

Comment: the answer supplemented

Comment: I don't understand why you are calculating the ratio of the resolution of the screen (1920/1280 and 1920/1440) for this. As you previously mentioned setting px is the solution, setting the :root to 10px instead of 62.5% of the default 16px (or 1px instead of 6.25%) is more than enough. The 62.5% thing comes from calculating what percentage from the 100% font-size default value would be 10px: `(100% * 10px)/16px`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font-size of html to 625%. Next You want to convert your CSS using my fast script:

```js
var css = replace(value, /[+-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)+rem/g, function (x) {
   return ( parseFloat( (parseFloat(x) * 0.1).toFixed(6) ) ) + "rem";
});
```

Finlay, your Safari rendering rem correctly.