# Why 1rem bigger then 1.1rem, 1.2rem etc

Tags: css, ios, responsive-design, font-size, device-width

Text with font-size: 1rem bigger then it should be:

[image: enormous 1rem text]

The problem reproduces only with all of this conditions:

1. ios
2. horizontal orientation
3. some text outside of span tag

HTML code:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>
                .t5 { font-size: 0.5rem;}
                .t6 { font-size: 0.6rem;}
                .t7 { font-size: 0.7rem;}
                .t8 { font-size: 0.8rem;}
                .t9 { font-size: 0.9rem;}
                .t10 { font-size: 1.0rem;}
                .t11 { font-size: 1.1rem;}
                .t12 { font-size: 1.2rem;}
                .t13 { font-size: 1.3rem;}
                .t14 { font-size: 1.4rem;}
                .t15 { font-size: 1.5rem;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            Some text<br />
            <span class="t5">Test text 0.5</span><br />
            <span class="t6">Test text 0.6</span><br />
            <span class="t7">Test text 0.7</span><br />
            <span class="t8">Test text 0.8</span><br />
            <span class="t9">Test text 0.9</span><br />
            <span class="t10">Test text 1.0</span><br />
            <span class="t11">Test text 1.1</span><br />
            <span class="t12">Test text 1.2</span><br />
            <span class="t13">Test text 1.3</span><br />
            <span class="t14">Test text 1.4</span><br />
            <span class="t15">Test text 1.5</span><br />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what if you try `1rem;` instead of `1.0rem;`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif same result

Answer (score 0):

You might be having this issue where iOS scaling the font to readable size. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266518/8080186) where you need to set `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`

Comment: There are no "incomplete tags". You can check it with validator: validator.w3.org

Comment: @DimaPavlov Did you try: `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none` ?

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by text outside san tag. You meant text not present within a tag but instead directly used alongside tags